# How to show full image height by use height 100% in div position absolute?

Tags: html, css

In div `class="photo"` it's position is absolute, I want to set it to 100% to show the image full height. But it's not working. How can I do this without setting it's height by px?

```css
.outside{
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 595px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto 0px;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px 0px #cfcfcf;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
.photo{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 315px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://web.arjentienkamp.com/codepen/tinder/photo1.jpg);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    cursor: move;
    user-select: none;
    touch-action: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.bottom{
    margin-top: 318px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of height, use bottom 0 and top 0

Comment: try on `.photo` - `background-size: contain;` and `height: 100%`

Comment: You want your image to be 100% of it's containing element, 100% of the full screen or 100% of its intrinsic height? Please specify

Comment: Do you need it to be the full width of the container or the full size of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, adding `height: 100%` and `background-size: contain` to your `.photo` class should do it:

```css
.outside{
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 595px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto 0px;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px 0px #cfcfcf;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
.photo{
    position: absolute;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://web.arjentienkamp.com/codepen/tinder/photo1.jpg);
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    cursor: move;
    user-select: none;
    touch-action: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.bottom{
    margin-top: 318px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```